# who gets the transaction fees?

Tags: mining-pools, transaction-fees

i heard that miner who get bitcoin first gets transaction fees.

Then who gets the transaction fee right when mine at mining pool? The miner or The pool?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the pool, because the miner (here: the pool) decides. Getting the fees and the block reward just means that you get to include a transaction spending those bitcoins. Typically, this transaction will transfer everything to a Bitcoin address owned by the pool, and the miners get individually paid by the pool.

There are different allocation schemes that pools use for this, but they all tend to be based on paying for not-quite finding blocks (solving a share), which occasionally but rarely will also happen to solve a block. Essentially, the pool is a bit of a risk insurance, taking in the infrequent but large rewards for hitting the jackpot of finding a new block, and dispensing smaller rewards for, typically, not-quite getting there by their individual miners.

So whether the pool pays a percentage (say 98%) of all it gets per block, including fees, or else excludes fees and keeps those entirely for itself, or uses some more complicated formula is entirely up to the pool to decide (and the individual miners to agree to by choosing that pool).